# Terraform Error : If multiple configurations are required, set the "alias" argument for alternative configurations [provider-azure]

Tags: azure, alias, terraform-provider-azure

[image]

Here im trying to add resources in azure portal in Terraform
I've tried setting alias but right after I made some changes in configuration file and I run terraform init command it throws an error like this

can anyone help me with this as I am newly working with Terraform and azure

NOTE: This is the error message I am getting

> DUPLICATE PROVIDER CONFIGURATION
>
> A DEFAULT (NON-ALIASED) PROVIDER CONFIGURATION FOR AZURERM WAS ALREADY
> GIVEN AT MAIN.TF 12,1-19 . IF MULTIPLE CONFIGURATIONS ARE REQUIRED SET
> THE "ALIAS" ARGUMENT FOR ALTERNATIVE CONFIGURATION.

Comment: Please edit your question so it contains the error output instead of an image.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you have already initialized terraform provider and azurerm provider in above . Again initializing it will error out with duplicate provider configuration.

So Please remove this block:

```
terraform {
  required_providers {
    azurerm = {
      source  = "hashicorp/azurerm"
      version = "~> 2.74"
    }
  }
  required_version = ">= 0.14.9"
}
```

And you can use directly the below:

```
provider "azurerm" {
    features {}
}
    
resource "azurerm_resource_group" "RG" {
  name     = "myRG"
  location = "WestUS2"
}

resource "azurerm_virtual_network" "vnet" {
  name                = "myvnet"
  location            = azurerm_resource_group.RG.location
  resource_group_name = azurerm_resource_group.RG.name
  address_space       = ["10.0.0.0/16"]

}
```

Comment: I want to add one more point here.. IF you are using multiple tf files in a folder try avoiding it as once you run a tf file the tfstate is created.. So adding providers to another file in same folder will error out as duplicate provider